# TableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, delegates

So I have added a `UIUITableView` to a `UIViewController`. I can't use a `UITableViewController` for reasons I don't need to explain since it will be unnecessary information. Anyway, I have set the `delegate`, and the data source to this viewController. I've added the delegate and datasource protocols as well. The cells are populated correctly, so the datasource is working fine. I can also scroll so it all works fine.

However, I can't get the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to trigger. It SHOULD trigger, but doesn't. I've read and a lot of issues with this can be correlated to a `UIGestureRecognizer`, but I haven't implemented one. I also use the standard UITableView, so not a custom made one.

If I long press the cells (3-4 sec) then it gets triggered as it's supposed to. This suggests that there is some issue with another view or something absorbing the tap gesture, which I have no control over. How would I solve this?

1. No, it's not did**De**selectRowAtIndexPath.
2. Yes all delegates and datasources are correct, since I can get the delegates/sources to trigger.
3. Yes, Single Selection is set on the TableView in the inspector.
4. Yes, everything has user interaction enabled.

If I just copy the code over to a `UITableViewController` it will work just fine, but right now that is not an option, I'm afraid. Anyone got any ideas on how to solve this? Most people who've had this issue has either had the issues in the list above, or added a `UIGesture` on top of the `UITableView` - I haven't.

Comment: Do you use custom `UITableViewCell`? It could be an issue. Did you try to use the "3D View of Xcode 6" to see if there was something "above" your UITableView catching the event?

Comment: How did you add the tableview - programmatically or through interface builder? Was the tableview added as a subview to self.view or to a different object such as a scrollview?

Comment: Also, are there process running that could be slowing down the app?

Comment: Ok.. i know people asking you to check something as trivial as whether your views are user interaction enabled can be annoying... and you have mentioned that **everything** is user interaction enabled ... just want to make sure if that includes the cell's content view.. and if not that, then have you checked if any of the cell's subviews are not stealing the touches..

Comment: You Impalement  UIGestureRecognizer code in your tableviewClass. if yes then remove and check.

Comment: @Larme I do not use a custom UITableViewCell (but I'd like to later on). I did just try the 3D view and it doesn't appear to be anything on top of the tableView.

Comment: @MikeE I added the TableView through the interface builder and the tableView was added to the self.view (I only dragged it from the IB, so I don't use any code at all). There are no processes slowing down the app.

Comment: @lukya Yes, the Cell's ContentView is set to enabled for user interaction as well. The cell currently displays nothing but a standard label, I haven't added anything to it yet.

Comment: @KiritModi as I wrote in the OP, I don't implement a UIGestureRecognizer, I don't even write my own UITableView class - I use the standard one.

Comment: @ClockWise Upload your code Example on http://ge.tt/ and give link to me

Answer (score 1):

I want to start by saying that I appreciate all the answers here provided, it gave me a lot of things to try out so I learned a lot - thanks! None of your suggestions worked, but simply because I'm a complete idiot. I said in the post that I did NOT implement a `UIGestureRecognizer`which I didn't...in that class, but in its super class. So I DID in fact implement it, but in a class that this ViewController was a subclass off. The only reason I didn't remember it was because I haven't looked at that super class for weeks.

Someone did suggest it in the comments that I should check for it, and I did and I was already certain I didn't implement one, so I quickly dismissed it. But now, after about 4 hours of debugging and recreating the project, adding things one by one, I eventually realized that the only thing that differed at this point was the Super Class, and the first piece of code I see when I open the file up was a GestureRecognizer...

So keep this in mind in the future everyone - I know I will. Thanks again for the help!

Sincerely,
The complete idiot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't add any controller in that cell, which covers the entire cell and also the user interaction of that controller is enabled.
Due to that controller's user interaction enabled the tap action is taken by that controller and when you long press that cell, that cell will receive your tap.

Example :

```
UIView *_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _cellWidth, _cellHeight)];
[_view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell.contentView addSubview:_view];
```

In the above case that view got your tap instated of the cell.

Comment: I haven't added anything to anything yet. All I have is a ViewController, its standard UIView, with a UITableView in it, which has a standard UITableViewCell added to it - all through interface builder. The ViewController implements the corresponding delegates for datasource and delegate of course, and these are also set in the IB for the TableView. I don't have a single line of code altering anything concerning the cell or the TableView other than delegate methods for the TableView :/